# Which Coroutine scope to use in AppWidgetProvider class?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am currently creating a widget and I am configuring the widget with a configuration activity and initializing the widget on onUpdate() of AppWidgetProvider. After that a CoroutineWorker will update the widget from time to time. I have set the updatePeriodMillis to 0.
So simply my code would be

```
override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
    if(!widget_configured)
    {
        //configure widget & start the service.
    }

}
```

So my question is can I wrap the code in the onUpdate function with a coroutine. If so what scope should I use. Is it GlobalScope.launch{}, or should I need to create a scope.
Is it safe to use something like this?

```
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        ex.printStackTrace()
})

override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        if(!widget_configured)
        {
            //configure widget & start the service.
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if(!widget_configured)
        {
            //configure widget & start the service.
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be the safest way to run a coroutine inside an appwidgetprovider. Please help me.

Comment: Once `onUpdate()` returns, your process can be terminated at any point. If you need to do I/O or something, IMHO that should all be inside the service (or `WorkManager` worker or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a coroutine for some reason, you should use GlobalScope or else it can be terminated at any point; unless you don't care if your widget gets the result or not, still your widget might not get the update ever which makes the task kind of pointless.

In any case, just be sure to minimize the number of update calls and the process intensity of the coroutine, you can easily consume lot of RAM if not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both mentioned ways can be used But, you need to cancel the job in onDeleted of the widgetProvider class so that there is no Memory leak for Long running tasks.
   GlobalScope.launch also returns a Job where you can cancel.